# Select query or select entries that don't start with a number - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select all entries that do not start with a number between 1-9.

**Example Entries**:

- 6300 Dog Lane
- Kitty Drive
- 500 Bird Chrest
- 800 Tire Road
- Johnson Ave
- Park Ave

**So if I ran a query on the above, I would expect**:

- Kitty Drive
- Johnson Ave
- Park Ave

The table is called `objects` and the column is called `location`.

**Something I tried**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, location FROM object WHERE location NOT LIKE '1%' OR '2%' OR '3%' OR '4%' OR '5%' OR '6%' OR '7%' OR '8%' OR '9%';
```

Unfortunately, that is unsuccessful.  Is this possible? If no, I will resort to modifying the data with Perl.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, location FROM object
       WHERE substring(location, 1, 1)
                  NOT IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
```

or you have to add `NOT LIKE` before every number:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, location FROM object
       WHERE location NOT LIKE '1%'
          OR location NOT LIKE '2%'
          ...
```

Comment: Trying the second way. I just need it to work doesn't have to look pretty.

Comment: I really appreciate this answer.  I was not aware that you could pull pull string locations.  That is completely awesome and useful for many things. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can use the following stntax:

```
SELECT column FROM TABLE where  column NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ;


SELECT DISTINCT name, location FROM object
                WHERE location NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$' ;
```

Comment: Well it works now, but it still polls all of the ones with numbers.

Comment: @kirskringle no. It's part of the standard distribution. What version are you using?

Comment: It's working, but the numbers still show the below answer solves the problem.

Comment: @Avidan you gave it good effort and you got votes up anyhow! Your answer is elegant and shows a really important thing.  Now I can go through my life using regex within queries!

Comment: @Avidan knowledge is power! If you figure it out please tell!

Answer (score 5):

Try this. It's simpler:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, location FROM object WHERE location NOT LIKE '[0-9]%';
```

Comment: I don't have access to MS SQL database right now. I work with oracle SQL server. this won't work in oracle SQL, for it to work there you have to use regexp_like

Answer (score 0):

What you "tried" needed to have `AND` instead of `OR`.  Also, `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.

If you have

```
INDEX(location)
```

this would probably be faster than any of the other answers:

```
( SELECT name, location FROM object
    WHERE location < '1'
) UNION ALL
( SELECT name, location FROM object
    WHERE location >= CHAR(ORD('9' + 1)) )
```

This technique only works for contiguous ranges of initial letters, such as `1..9`.

A somewhat related question:  [Should I perform regex filtering in MySQL or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47142360/should-i-perform-regex-filtering-in-mysql-or-php) -- it asks about fetching rows starting with 1..9 instead of the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for SQL Server:

```
select column_name
from table
where substring(column_name,1,1) not in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score -1):

`ISNUMERIC` should work. (will exclude 0 as well).

Sample code -

```
ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(location, 1, 1)) = 0
```

Comment: `ISNUMERIC` is not a built-in function in MySql