# Should I perform regex filtering in MySQL or PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a MySQL column which holds various string data, it is a VARCHAR field.

The table has more than 100k records, and I'd like to filter a query by this field to SELECT only the records in which this field starts with any characters but 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

Is it faster to:

- write a REGEXP in the SQL query, or
- just select all records and filter them out in PHP by performing a PHP REGEX?

Comment: It's likely much faster in MySQL. See [Select Query | Select Entires That Don't Start With A Number - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937023/select-query-select-entires-that-dont-start-with-a-number-mysql)

Comment: Do it on the database, that way you are not returning a massive amount of redundant data.  This type of thing is exactly what databases are designed to do.

Comment: Your second option is absolutely not good. When it's about db data access, let the VERY powerful db engine do all the possible jobs. No matter how complex the sql statements become.

Comment: Don't worry about faster.  The difference will be insignificant except under huge volumes of data.  Instead, focus on which is easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @AndyLester a for loop in PHP on 100K records will definitely show a performance drop. Believe me, I've tried it...

Comment: For this particular query, I agree with the comments above, but bear in mind that PHP's REGEX capabilities far exceed MySQL's, so, for more complex expressions, you may be obliged to consider option 2, or some hybrid strategy.

Comment: Would it be so hard to test? We can't answer this for you. Generally such operations will be much faster in the database (and note that given your requirement, using a regex is probably the slowest possible and least efficient solution to the problem) but if your database is already a bottleneck, then it may make more sense to do it in PHP - the latter is much easier to scale. Facebook, for example, do a lot of their sorting in PHP despite database being much better at it - simply because they can easily add php servers.

Comment: I disagree, there is no benefit or advantage in offloading a task from a system designed to do that task to a system that can do it, but less well.

Comment: Is not necessary. You can use a LIKE SQL statement instead of REGEX (but you need to cast the records as a string). I wrote an entry some time ago about the use of LIKE in MSSQL (it's written in spanish, but I provide a lot of examples) [WHERE](http://arcigo.blogspot.mx/2017/04/diseno-de-base-de-datos-parte-viii-where.html). Another way to do that it's using NOT IN SQL statement So, use a SQL query to filter your records

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query will be faster, hands down. This sort of thing is precisely what SQL is meant to be used for.

To clarify for future reference: when you need the DB to return a specific data set, you should let the DB deal with constructing the dataset by using a SQL query. Your application code can then have one or more abstractions that represent and handle the resulting dataset for your business use case, but it should not do the DB engine's job.

TL;DR: building a dataset from DB tables is a Data access layer concern, handling abstractions related to business entities is the application layer concern

Answer (score 0):

I reopened because the dup ([Select Query | Select Entires That Don't Start With A Number - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937023/select-query-select-entires-that-dont-start-with-a-number-mysql)) had the inverse condition -- "rows *not* starting with ..."

There is a significant optimization for rows *starting* with some consecutive set of characters, such as 1..9:

```
INDEX(col)

SELECT ... WHERE col >= '1'
             AND col  < CHAR(ORD('9') + 1)
```

This would scan only the 1..9 rows, not the entire table, such as the PHP approach would require, and such that all three answers on the other Question require.

A second reason this is not a dup of that other one -- the Question here is more about PHP vs MySQL.  The main performance argument for doing it in MySQL is to save the transmission time.

If you need a fancier `REGEXP`, you could switch to MariaDB, which has (I think) the same regexp engine as PHP.  If you need something too complex for SQL, even with a better regexp, then you may be forced to go to PHP.  But even in that case, filter as much as you can in SQL -- to minimize the amount of data being shoveled over the 'wire'.